# Docker service won't start on Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL2

Tags: 22.04, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After having installed docker following some tutorials, such as this one:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-22-04

I try to start the docker service, and it says it's trying to start (the systemctl thing won't work for me since I get `System has not been booted with systemd as init system`):

```
$ sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker
```

but it never start as shown when running

```
$ sudo service docker status
 * Docker is not running
```

Answer (score 16):

As Marco said here:

https://crapts.org/2022/05/15/install-docker-in-wsl2-with-ubuntu-22-04-lts/

The steps to fix this are:

1. `sudo update-alternatives --config iptables`
2. Type number "1" and press Enter to select "iptables-legacy"
3. `sudo service docker start`

Comment: This worked today for my Ubuntu 22.04 running inside Windows 10. Thanks

Comment: This is not working for me !!! Still shows * Docker is not running